# Cannot read property of undefined in json using backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a json file like this:

```
 "_id": {
                "$oid": "d8"
            },
"timestamp": {
                "$date": "2010-09-03T11:53:22Z"
            },
"name": {
                "$ref": "user",
                "$id": "73e"
            },
```

and in backbone collection I have this, and i want to fetch data from url.

```
defaults : {
                id : null,
                name : null,
                timestamp : null

            },
parse : function(response){
                response.id = response._id.$oid;
                response.timestamp = response.timestamp.$date;
                response.name = response.name.$ref;

                return response;
            },
```

it recognize everything except ref and it ways this error.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$ref' of undefined. Why is it like that?

Comment: With a few assumptions, but it seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/zGpP4/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I want to use console.log(response); in view and the parse function be in model (separate files) , how can I use it? I did console.log(CustomerModel.response); in which CustomerModel is the name of my model. but it printed "undefined" since it did not recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

You got JSON that you do not expect to get. You always have to check if object exists before accessing it properties:

```
parse : function (response) {
    response._id && (response.id = response._id.$oid);
    response.timestamp && (response.timestamp = response.timestamp.$date);
    response.name && (response.name = response.name.$ref);

    return response;
}
```

Please add to your question console output: `console.log(response);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I want to use console.log(response); in view and the parse function be in model (separate files) , how can I use it? I did console.log(CustomerModel.response); in which CustomerModel is the name of my model. but it printed "undefined" since it did not recognize it.

Comment: model -> `parse : function (response) { console.log(response); /*...*/ }`

Comment: I put that in parse but nothing shown in debugger, since it is in Model and nothing call this. in order to show sth in debugger shall I put it in initialize function or sth like that?

Comment: You should see a response output in console because in this method you have an error as you said. Have you put console.log at the top?